# C, data structure

Tags: c, data-structures

In google search when we type a letter, many suggestions come up ,usually its related to history of the keywords searched before.

So, whats the data structure used to store the history of those keywords so that as soon as we type a letter, the suggestions are displayed?

Comment: So if I type “a” it will show suggestions as arx , arpita etcand when i type “ar” it will suggest as arpita arjita etc. So, how are these strings stored .

Answer (score 0):

Google undoubtedly has something more complex, but you could start with a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). It's a tree data structure where each node represents strings starting with a particular prefix. As you descend the trie you get longer and longer strings.

[image: Trie example]